# Hazelcast member is sending the invalid join request to another cluster running on the same host

Tags: hazelcast

We have two applications , say A & B having their own hazelcast cluster (via TCP) and runs on the same machines. Here the issue is that the cluster member belongs to application A is keep sending invalid join requests to other member belong to application B for every 2 mins.

**Expected behavior**
Though this join request is ignored, the application log events are growing unnecessarily with the below event.

**Log Event**
[hz.reports-NodeA.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] [WARN] com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterJoinManager -- [NodeA]:5702 [hazelcast-reports] [5.3.0] Received an invalid join request from [NodeB]:5701, cause: members part of different cluster

We tried to assign unique instance name for every member in the cluster, but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set ports on `member-list`, each cluster will probe the same default range of ports (5701 to 5703), find a process and attempt to join with it.

For one cluster something like this should fix:

```
  network:
    port:
      port: 6701
    join:
      auto-detection:
        enabled: false
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - 127.0.0.1:6701
          - 127.0.0.1:6702
```

The `port: 6701` indicates which port this process should try to use.
The `127.0.0.1:6701` & `127.0.0.1:6702` indicate the places to probe.